# adddate(curdate(), -(day(curdate())-1)) and concat(last_day(curdate()),' 23:59:59')

Tags: php, mysql

What exactly is this mysql script means time BETWEEN ?

```
     ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -(DAY(CURDATE())-1)) AND CONCAT(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()),' 23:59:59')
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DAY(CURDATE())-1` is the current day of the month, less 1. For today (Aug 15, 2013), the value would be 14. Subtract 14 days from August 15 and you have August 1. In other words, `ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -(DAY(CURDATE())-1))` gives you the first day of the month.

`LAST_DAY(CURDATE())` gives you the last day of the month. If you call it today it will return August 31, 2013. Append the `23:59:59` and you have the last second of the last day of the month.

In other words, if called on August 15, 2013, the values come out as `2013-08-01` and `2013-08-31 23:59:59`. If this range is applied against a `DATETIME` value, it means "anything in the month of August 2013".

This is actually a pretty good way to check for date/time values within a month because it avoids using a function on the MySQL column that holds the date/time. If the column has an index, the index will (probably) be used for optimization. One approach I often see is this:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(myDateTime, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m')
```

This reads a little better, but it kills optimization. I'd stick with the expression you already have.

Comment: thanks Ed Gibbs its not my script I just wanted to know what exact is that all about they mark it all negative :(

Comment: I thought your question was legit enough because it was obvious it wasn't your code. The down votes were probably because there was no research effort shown, and that's unfortunately legit too. If you could do it over again, I'd recommend (a) stating it's not your code and (b) showing that you reviewed the various functions (`CURDATE`, `DATE_ADD`, `DAY`) but didn't understand how they worked together.